# Unclear point in outlier construction based on an heavy-tail distribution

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

The following is an example from a book (An Introduction to Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by P. Fieguth, page 417) on random variables and random vectors. Please consider the following.

[image]

Question: What does this mean?:

"there are outliers present with a variance
$\nu^2$ times as large as the sample variance."

Why $\nu^2$ times as large as the sample variance?

Answer (score 0):

I think what this meant to say is " there are outliers present with a variance $v^2$
times as large as the variance of 90% of the sample" or something along those lines.

For $v^2=10$, $\hat{\sigma}=1.9$, so outlier distribution has ~5x the variance of sample. For $v^2=100$ $\hat{\sigma}=10.9$, outlier distribution has ~10x the sample variance, which is also the long run ratio for $v^2$ large, since 0.9 becomes negligible and only $\hat{\sigma} \propto v^2 / 10$ remains